# Can we use two radio receivers on drone with different frequencies to increase range possibilities and safety?

Tags: receiver, safety

I think about installing additional 915MHz receiver into drone which has 2.4GHz receiver. I want to keep controls when 2.4GHz is jammed or drone flied too far (or behind large obstacle).

But opposite team will try to hack and steal our drone during the flight, so, it's a bit dangerous to have two simultaneously working receivers when we use only one.

Does this idea have a sence? Is it possible to add reserve communication line to drone with keeping safety (maybe receivers can be switched in some way)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any flight controller software that accepts multiple receiver inputs, although some receivers can use multiple 'satellite' receivers bound to the same transmitter.

Generally, if people think they might exceed the range of 2.4GHz, they fit 915MHz radio and use it all the time. There's very little drawback, if you've already bought the more expensive receiver and found space for the larger antenna.

If you were writing your own FC firmware, it would be easy enough to read two inputs from two UARTs, but you'd need a way to decide which to use when they're both valid.